# Can I get Apache to tell me which configuration file an error is in?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have some strange error messages in my Apache error log:

```
Line: 106 Error: syntax error at token &
Line: 81 Error: syntax error at token $
```

Now my *guess* is that these refer to an error in some configuration file.  However, the message is decidedly unhelpful as to *which* configuration file produces the error.  The main configuration files pass the `apachectl configtest` test so I guess it isn't in one of those which means that it is probably in an `.htaccess` somewhere.  Is there a way to make these error messages a little more informative?  How does apache count lines?  Is it per-file, or on a global basis?

(The system is apache2 on Linux, if that helps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not apache log messages; they're most likely CGI or PHP (whichever you use).

`apachectl configtest` does not validate "the main files"- it validates the *configuration* - all of it.

(.htaccess files are NOT part of ***the*** configuration.)

.htaccess failures are not logged as "files"- they just produce a 500 error.

Comment: I assumed that they weren't PHP error messages as they didn't seem to be related to a particular request.  PHP error messages seem to follow the pattern "[Date Time] [error] [client IP] PHP Warning: warning in file line number" whereas these were just the lines I quoted: no context whatsoever.  The previous error in the log file was about a missing favicon.

Comment: If an .htaccess file contains invalid data, apache will log a 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: However, that did give me the hint to go digging further and I found a few more examples some of which complained about `$$`.  Complaining about `$` and `$$` and complaining about *tokens* is a very TeX-like thing to do and, sure enough, I'm running a TeX-like process elsewhere and these errors are from *that*.  So thanks for the help - I now know I can safely ignore them.

Comment: Why on earth would there be TeX errors in a web server error log ?

Comment: I said **TeX-like**, not TeX.  It's an instiki installation running itex2MML as part of the wiki-to-XHTML conversion.  (However, as I'd installed some PHP stuff I was watching the error logs with PHP in my head and had forgotten about this other part, hence my initial confusion.)

Comment: I'm glad I only understood half of that :)